# C# cannot find a used and referenced class

Tags: c#, namespaces

I and a few friends are building a program made from 4 projects we are putting together.

While developing, we decided to move a class from one project to another. We changed the namespace and made sure all of the projects reference to the one containing it.

When running the project, the compiler gives a couple of error:

```
The type or namespace name 'dataList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Cannot implicitly convert type 'DAL.dataList`1<classes.IBase>' to 'classes.dataList<classes.IBase>'

dataList is the class we moved from DAL to classes.
```

The class appears colored, and when I attempt to show the location by doing `classes.dataList`, it recognizes the class, but the compiler still gives the error.

A problem that appeared to one of us was an internal conflict that the compiler was reading from a deleted old file instead of the correct one (so it failed to load it properly), but it was fixed, and now this popped up.

Comment: Sounds like the class has not been moved but rather copied and you have it in two places.

Comment: There was actually another copy which I didn't know about (wasn't where it was supposed to be) but deleting it didn't affect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved- I'm not entirely sure why or how. As far as I gathered, one of us played with the DAL, added and removed the references and it solved the issue.